# Python Django Dynamic Rest API Parameter

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a Rest API with Django for collecting web traffic like google analytic did. Is it possible to create an dynamic rest API parameter with POST request something like this

```
http POST localhost:8000/collect/ pr1nm=abc pr2nm=bcd
```

with limit dynamic parameter from 1-200, so we could use pr1nm until pr200nm.
So far, I use json data on my request like

```
http POST localhost:8000/collect/ productname='{"pr1nm":"abc", "pr2nm":"bcd"}'
```

the reason why we want to do that because we also need to validate this payload to google analytic measurement protocol (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) which is need dynamic parameter (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#pr_nm)

any ideas? thanks before!

Comment: Have you considered using the urls query parameters?  I.e. `localhost:8000/collect/?pr1nm=abc&pr2nm=bcd`.  You can access these through `request.query_params` in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @a-j-parr for your suggestion for my input request, and this is the way I've done to solve my issue.

in views.py, I converted the data to dictionary

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def add_payload(request):
    received_data = dict(request.GET)
    # celery task
    task_add_payload.delay(received_data)
```

and then in the task.py, I use regular expression to filter the query parameters. with exact format ( example : pr200nm where pr+number+nm )

```
@app.task(name="add-payload-task")
def task_add_payload(received_data):
    import re
    for key in received_data.keys():
        if re.match(r"pr\d+nm$", key):
            # save to dictionary/list and then save to pr_nm table.
```

thanks.